# Issue with dynamically creating LinkButton not going into command (C#/ASp.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I am dynamically creating a table in C# with ASP.NET, and each row will have a LinkButton for the user to delete the record. Problem is right now is that the page never goes into the command at all - I've put breakpoints there and it just doesn't go into there. Here is my code:

```
 protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
            {

                ColorConverter conv = new ColorConverter();
                string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TPRTestConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                TPRDBDataContext dc = new TPRDBDataContext();
                DataContext db = new DataContext(connection);
                Table<SageAccount> SageAccount = db.GetTable<SageAccount>();
                Table<InvoiceItem> InvoiceItem = db.GetTable<InvoiceItem>();
                Table<Invoice> Invoice = db.GetTable<Invoice>();
                Boolean alloweditting = (from s in dc.Invoices where s.id.ToString() == Request.QueryString["id"] select s.alloweditting).Single();
                if (alloweditting == false)
                {
                    dtlsInsert.Visible = false;
                    modalPanel.Visible = false;
                }
                int sagepk = (from s in dc.Invoices where s.id.ToString() == Request.QueryString["id"] select s.sageaccount).Single();
                lblSageID.Text = (from s in dc.SageAccounts where s.ID == sagepk select s.SageID).Single();
                lblDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();


                Table table = new Table();
                table.GridLines = GridLines.None;
                //table.BorderWidth = 1;
                //table.BorderColor = (System.Drawing.Color)conv.ConvertFromString("black");
                table.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
                table.GridLines = (GridLines)3;

                TableHeaderRow header = new TableHeaderRow();
                header.BackColor = (System.Drawing.Color)conv.ConvertFromString("#EDEDED");
                foreach (string header2 in new string[] { "", "Quantity", "Rate", "Description", "Nominal Code", "Subtotal" })
                {
                    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                    cell.Text = header2;
                    header.Cells.Add(cell);
                }

                table.Rows.Add(header);

                var data = (from s in dc.InvoiceItems where s.invoiceid.ToString() == Request.QueryString["id"].ToString() select s);
                foreach (var x in data)
                {

                    TableRow row = new TableRow();
                    if (x.invoicetext == null)
                    {
                        decimal total;
                        try
                        {
                            total = (decimal)x.rate * (decimal)x.quantity;
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            total = 0;
                        }
                        int i = 0;
                        foreach (string columnData in new string[] { x.id.ToString(), x.quantity.ToString(), x.rate.ToString(), x.description, x.nominalcode, total.ToString("N2") })
                        {
                            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                            {
                                if (i == 0)
                                {
                                    LinkButton lnkdel = new LinkButton();
                                    lnkdel.Text = "Delete";
                                    lnkdel.ID = "lnkDel" + Guid.NewGuid();

                                    if (alloweditting == false)
                                    {
                                        lnkdel.Enabled = false;
                                    }
                                    lnkdel.Font.Bold = false;
                                    lnkdel.CommandArgument = x.id.ToString();
                                    lnkdel.Command += lnkdel_Command;

                                    cell.Controls.Add(lnkdel);
                                    i++;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    cell.Text = columnData;
                                }


                            }

                            row.Cells.Add(cell);
                        }



                        runningtotal = runningtotal + total;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int i = 0;

                        foreach (string columnData in new string[] { x.id.ToString(), x.invoicetext })
                        {
                            TableCell cell = new TableCell();

                            if (i == 0)
                            {
                                LinkButton lnkdel = new LinkButton();
                                lnkdel.Text = "Delete";
                                lnkdel.ID = "lnkDel" + Guid.NewGuid();

                                if (alloweditting == false)
                                {
                                    lnkdel.Enabled = false;
                                }
                                lnkdel.Font.Bold = false;
                                lnkdel.CommandArgument = x.id.ToString();



                                cell.Controls.Add(lnkdel);
                                i++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                cell.Text = columnData;
                                cell.ColumnSpan = 5;
                            }
                            row.Cells.Add(cell);

                        }

                    }

                    switch (x.formatoptions)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            row.ForeColor = (System.Drawing.Color)conv.ConvertFromString("black");
                            row.Font.Bold = false;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            row.ForeColor = (System.Drawing.Color)conv.ConvertFromString("black");
                            row.Font.Bold = true;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            row.ForeColor = (System.Drawing.Color)conv.ConvertFromString("red");
                            row.Font.Bold = false;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            row.ForeColor = (System.Drawing.Color)conv.ConvertFromString("red");
                            row.Font.Bold = true;
                            break;
                    }
                    table.Rows.Add(row);
                }

                TableFooterRow row2 = new TableFooterRow();
                TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
                cell2.Text = "<span style\"text-align: right; width: 100%;\">Total = <b>" + runningtotal.ToString("N2") + "</b></span>";
                cell2.ColumnSpan = 6;
                row2.Cells.Add(cell2);
                table.Rows.Add(row2);

                var update = (from s in dc.Invoices where s.id.ToString() == Request.QueryString["id"] select s).Single();
                update.total = runningtotal;

                dc.SubmitChanges();
                datatable.Controls.Clear();
                datatable.Controls.Add(table);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("Invoices.aspx");
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



        }


        protected void lnkdel_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TPRTestConnectionString"].ConnectionString;


            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
            {
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM InvoiceItem WHERE id = @id", conn);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                conn.Open();
                try
                {
                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write(ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: why are you subscribing *two* handlers for the `Command` event? (`lnkdel_Command`, and then the anonymous delegate). also, try changing the `lnkdel_Command` accessibility modifier to `protected` (not `private`)

Comment: Ah sorry, bit of debugging code still lingering around. I've changed my code now as you can see. I also changed it to protected as you can see, but it still doesn't go into that method for some reason.

Comment: You should also post the asp.net code related to the LinkButton.

Comment: hmm ok. man i hate dynamically created linkbuttons. just have a look on google to see how many problems there are. :) another guess, try changing to `lnkdel.Command += new CommandEventHandler(this.lnkdel_Command);`

Comment: Hal - the link button is dynamically created so there's no ASP.NET code. RPM - Cheers buddy, it's giving me this error now: "Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: handler "

Comment: You have two branches of your code adding the Delete buttons, but you're only attaching the event handler in the first branch. Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the `if (x.invoicetext == null)` line? I suspect that may be your problem.

Comment: Sorry, indeed that was the issue. But although the page 'works' now it still never goes into the command :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `lnkdel.Command += lnkdel_Command;`

should be like

```
lnkdel.Command += new CommandEventHandler(this.lnkdel);
```

Comment: It still doesn't go into the method at all =[

Comment: lnkdel.Command += lnkdel_Command; is valid which removes redundant delegate.